# RocketMQ start error, print message: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup

Tags: exception, startup, nameservers, rocketmq

operating environment:
- CentOS Linux release 7.8.2003 (Core)
- openjdk version "11.0.8" 2020-07-14 LTS
- rocketmq-all-4.7.1-bin-release

preamble:
In order to get up and running quickly, I'll download a binary release. no need to build the binary artifact.

Description of the problem:
Since the RocketMQ startup script doesn't support java11, I've made changes to the startup file based on a web search, modify files with runserver.sh, runbroker.sh, and tools.sh for roughly the same idea. and the configuration file is as follows.

**runserver.sh**

```
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms4g -Xmx4g -Xmn2g -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=320m"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms500m -Xmx500m -Xmn250m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=320m"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseCMSCompactAtFullCollection -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8  -XX:-UseParNewGC"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:CMSInitiatingOccupancyFraction=70 -XX:+CMSParallelRemarkEnabled -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0 -XX:+CMSClassUnloadingEnabled -XX:SurvivorRatio=8"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -verbose:gc -Xloggc:${GC_LOG_DIR}/rmq_srv_gc_%p_%t.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -verbose:gc -Xlog:gc:${GC_LOG_DIR}/rmq_srv_gc_%p_%t.log"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=30m"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:-UseLargePages"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -Djava.ext.dirs=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${BASE_DIR}/lib:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext"
#JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9555,server=y,suspend=n"
```

**runbroker.sh**

```
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms8g -Xmx8g -Xmn4g"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms500m -Xmx500m -Xmn250m"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:+UseG1GC -XX:G1HeapRegionSize=16m -XX:G1ReservePercent=25 -XX:InitiatingHeapOccupancyPercent=30 -XX:SoftRefLRUPolicyMSPerMB=0"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -verbose:gc -Xloggc:${GC_LOG_DIR}/rmq_broker_gc_%p_%t.log -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -XX:+PrintGCApplicationStoppedTime -XX:+PrintAdaptiveSizePolicy"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -verbose:gc -Xlogi:gc:${GC_LOG_DIR}/rmq_broker_gc_%p_%t.log"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:+UseGCLogFileRotation -XX:NumberOfGCLogFiles=5 -XX:GCLogFileSize=30m"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:+AlwaysPreTouch"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:MaxDirectMemorySize=15g"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -XX:-UseLargePages -XX:-UseBiasedLocking"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -Djava.ext.dirs=${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${BASE_DIR}/lib:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext"
#JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,address=9555,server=y,suspend=n"
```

**tools.sh**

```
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms1g -Xmx1g -Xmn256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m"
JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -server -Xms500m -Xmx500m -Xmn256m -XX:MetaspaceSize=128m -XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=128m"
# JAVA_OPT="${JAVA_OPT} -Djava.ext.dirs=${BASE_DIR}/lib:${JAVA_HOME}/jre/lib/ext:${JAVA_HOME}/lib/ext"
```

**initiate RocketMQ NameServer**

```
./mqnamesrv
[0.008s][info][gc] Using G1
错误: 找不到或无法加载主类 org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup
原因: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.rocketmq.namesrv.NamesrvStartup
```

After that, I try to add the environment variable ROCKETMQ_HOME to point to my RocketMQ directory, The results are still the same.

```
ROCKETMQ_HOME=/home/rocketmq-all-4.7.1-bin-release
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should run RocketMQ on JDK 1.8.

Comment: Thank you very much.
It eliminated this problem when I was using JDK8 and I think it may have been caused between RocketMQ and the JDK version. But there is no better solution.